# TV episode where people are in a cave/tunnel and get teleported to the other coast

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking to identify a movie or more probably TV series episode I saw in the nineties.

In this movie, two (possibly young) adults are in some kind of cave or rather tunnel, when a mysterious blue/white flashing thing bursts through the tunnel. That flash has the effect of teleporting them somewhere, and they wake up on a beach, and they see the sun setting in the ocean they are looking at from the beach.
The following conversation goes something like this:
-How long have we been asleep? The sun is setting already! -That's not sunset, it's sunrise! -But that means we are on the east coast now?

The gist of the conversation is that the sunset/sunrise is wrong for the coast that they live on, and they conclude they have been teleported to the other side of the continent.

I vaguely remember another scene that involves spiders (not big horror-film type, just regular size spiders) and that being bitten by them has some influence on what is happening. But my memory is very hazy here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like **Earth2**, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_2_(TV_series) for description.  There was a tunnel that the Grendlers (native hunter-gatherers) used that transported them from one location to another (actually through the planet) which they used to gather supplies.  And the new colonists followed them through.

Can't remember specific episodes, but this link also notes the spiders you reference: http://www.tor.com/2012/03/16/colonization-is-no-joke-earth2/

> Grendlers are race of generally peaceful grunting little scavenger rhino frog troll thingies become thirsty for blood, there are a lot of **spiders**, and there’s a time-dimension tunnel mini warp hole across the planet. Any of those elements could be made into something interesting. You’d think, for example, that when everyone is freezing their asses off in winter, the fact that they can instantly zoom across to the seaside might be something of an advantage, yes? No. The tunnel doesn’t make another appearance. Nor do the blood thirsty Grendlers, who it turns out were influenced by the positive or negative sides of the tunnel. Did I mention it affects emotions? Yeah, because that makes perfect sense. All in all, it’s a throw-away episode.

Comment: Spot on. It looks like it's Earth 2 "Brave New Pacifica". Reading the reviews it seems hardly worth rewatching though. Thanks anyway!